# Adding multiple Overlays on map view takes more time

Tags: mkmapview, mkoverlay

I'm trying to add multiple overlays of about 1500 on map view. I'm getting the locations from database and adding them on map view. The time to get data from database is very low but the time it takes to draw them on map is very high which is about 30 sec and I want to add overlays based on zoom levels, like level<4 1000 overlays, >=4 2000 overlays, redrawing these overlays screwed me. Please show me the solution to add them in a less amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

I've had another problem with multiple overlays, it is causing memory issues on an actual device (Not the sim). The solution to this was creating one overlay from all. This might also be the solution to your problem as drawing the "combined-overlay" should be a lot faster:

The credits go to [this answer and the code provided on the Apple Dev-forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370328/multiple-mkoverlays-on-a-mkmapview-lead-to-memory-warnings?answertab=active#tab-top)

You then should be able to create one overlay from all and then draw that one overlay on the map.
Basically you create a class that handles the multiple overlays and draws them together onto on OverlayView