# Multiple Polygon overlays from array

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkpolygon, mkpolygonview

I have an array with polygons created from a data file with coordinates per polygon.

So when I plot them on my map I use:

```
[mapView addOverlays:polygonArray];
```

and in my viewForOverlay:

```
if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]) {
    MKPolygonView *polyView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay];
    polyView.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];
    polyView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];
    polyView.lineWidth = 1;
    return polyView;
  }
else {
  return nil;
}
```

The problem is that regarding my "colorWithAlphaComponent" the code seems to reuse and recreate the polyView for each Polygon. Therefore the first one is with alpha 0.1 but the second is 2x and so on.. So the last few Polygons aren't "seethrough" anymore.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Do the polygons overlap?  Is it possible to merge them into one polygon?  A link to a picture of the issue may help.  The map view may be blending the colors of the overlays that overlap (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-BCIGICEF).  If you can't merge the overlapping polygons into one, you may have to implement the drawing manually using a custom overlay view.

Comment: First thanks for helping out! They don't always overlap, overlapping isn't the problem. For more clarity, [I've added an image](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/1280/y56.png "Image of polygons on map") I think the problem is in the "viewForOverlay", where it recreates each polygon until the last one is drawn?

Comment: It looks like you are adding the same polygon multiple times so it gets overlapped with itself.  Is addOverlays called multiple times in the app?  If so, does the polygonArray contain previously-added polygons or just new ones?

Comment: Ah I was looking for the problem at the wrong place... Although there were no previously-added polygons, it had some polygons multiple times because of a wrong piece of code... That was causing the problem. Thanks for helping out. Is there any way to credit your help here? Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @wkberg can u please give me code to add multiple polygon from array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the problem description and picture, it sounds like you are adding the same polygon multiple times so it gets overlapped with itself.

When overlays overlap, the map view blends their colors together resulting in a darker appearance.

If `polygonArray` contains unique polygons itself but `addOverlays` is called multiple times, you should call `removeOverlays` before `addOverlays` if the existing polygons on the map are already included in `polygonArray`.

Another possibility is that `polygonArray` itself contains duplicate polygons.
Even if `addOverlays` is called only once, the map will add multiple instances of the same polygon resulting in those overlays overlapping themselves giving them a darker color than expected.

To fix this, you should eliminate the duplication in `polygonArray`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction! ;-) My problem was duplication in the `polygonArray`. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: By the way, I want to add that using multiple polygons isn't that great for mapkit as it doesn't reuse them. It creates a new layer for each polygon. It works fine on the iOS-sim, but not on a actual device as it doesn't have the memory-capacity of the sim. Therefore used [this anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370328/multiple-mkoverlays-on-a-mkmapview-lead-to-memory-warnings?answertab=active#tab-top) to make plot all polygons in one polygonView. So instead of reusing them it only creates one overlay from all. This only adds one layer and reducing the mem-usage significantly! :D